# How to get the row number of the last row of a range in Exce VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any method or property by which I can get the row number of last row in a range **no matter if that row is totally empty**? like

```
Range("A2:B4").Rows.Lastrow
```

will return "4" even the row 4 is totally empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
Range("A2:B4").Row + Range("A2:B4").rows.count -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate Selection.Areas to find a bottom row in case of multiple selection and use the method toy posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that returns the row number for a range

```
Split(MyRange.Rows.Address, "$")(4)
```

Hope this helps